# Apply formula to Multi-index column Python

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, multi-index

Thank you in advance for your help.

New enough to pandas to be dangerous.

Want to apply formula and label result to multi-index dataframe.

Below works:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

N = 100
dates = pd.date_range('19971002', periods=N, freq='B')
df =pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(dates),2),index=dates,columns=list('AB')) 
df1 =pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(dates),2),index=dates,columns=list('AB'))
```

I add two columns, 'pattern'(for label) & 'delta'(formula).

```
df['pattern'] = 'foo'
df['delta'] = df.A - df.B
df.loc[(df.A > df.B),'pattern']= 'bar'
df.loc[(df.A < df.B),'pattern'] = 'bat'  

df.head()

                A       B          pattern  delta
1997-10-02  -0.685254   2.264847    bat -2.950101
1997-10-03  -1.087783   1.953508    bat -3.041291
1997-10-06  1.094727    0.612298    bar 0.482429
1997-10-07  -1.093363   1.791276    bat -2.884639
1997-10-08  -0.916725   2.225537    bat -3.142262
```

I get into trouble when I concat two dataframes.  Want to combine df & df1 into single data frame so I can get highest values of 'bar' & 'bat', along with additional column identifying if data(row) came from from DF or DF1.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1, keys=['DF', 'DF1']))

df.head()
            DF                      DF1
            A           B           A           B
1997-10-02  0.360254    -0.477511   -0.017894   0.226474
1997-10-03  -0.226963   -1.302804   -1.615174   -0.330607
1997-10-06  0.524860    2.597518    -0.041241   1.432354
1997-10-07  -0.672445   1.741740    0.011852    0.013495
1997-10-08  0.969295    0.240990    0.682385    0.875781
```

I've tried several things like:

```
data['value'] = 'foo'
data['delta'] = data.A - data.B
data.loc[(data.A > data.B),'pattern']= 'bar'
data.loc[(data.A < data.B),'pattern'] = 'bat'
```

and get error messages.

Gut tells me I need to group-by and then apply formula, I can handle that (I think), but how do I bring label('pattern') along?

Goal is:

```
            Column pattern delta
1997-10-02  DF     bat     -2.950101
1997-10-03  DF     bat     -3.041291
1997-10-06  DF1    bar     0.482429
1997-10-07  DF     bat     -2.884639
1997-10-08  DF1    bat     -3.142262
```

Thank you once again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can get most of the way there simply by stacking and then doing the groupby:

```
data = data.stack(level=0)
data['pattern'] = 'foo'
data['delta'] = data.A - data.B
data.loc[(data.A > data.B),'pattern']= 'bar'
data.loc[(data.A < data.B),'pattern'] = 'bat'  
final = data.loc[data.groupby(level=0)["delta"].idxmax()]
```

gives me something like

```
>>> final
                       A         B pattern     delta
1997-10-02 DF   0.536219 -1.019708     bar  1.555927
1997-10-03 DF   1.702837 -1.204639     bar  2.907477
1997-10-06 DF1  0.448117  0.302420     bar  0.145697
1997-10-07 DF  -0.563475  0.778225     bat -1.341700
1997-10-08 DF   1.072564  0.695792     bar  0.376772
1997-10-09 DF   0.739936 -0.290353     bar  1.030290
1997-10-10 DF1 -0.124411  0.351603     bat -0.476014
1997-10-13 DF1 -0.390445 -0.208104     bat -0.182341
1997-10-14 DF1 -0.153270 -1.464505     bar  1.311235
1997-10-15 DF1  0.081881 -1.382577     bar  1.464458
```

where you can reset the index and change the column names as you like.  This works because the stacking pulls the DFs in the columns out:

```
>>> data.stack(level=0)
                       A         B
1997-10-02 DF   0.060752 -0.858375
           DF1  0.923508 -1.188595
1997-10-03 DF  -0.820430 -1.964643
           DF1 -0.989516 -0.916772
[...]
```

Finally, because `.idxmax()` gives us the index at which `delta` reaches its maximum, we can use that to index into the frame.

---

Aside: this is more personal preference than anything else, but I like to use `np.sign` (1 for positive, 0 for 0, and -1 for negative) and then `replace` rather than three lines for your `pattern` translation.  For example:

```
np.sign(data["delta"]).replace({1: "bar", 0: "foo", -1: "bat"})
```